# Jenkins archiveArtifcats attach latest file in directory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

ls ../images

1.tgz 2.tgz 3.tgz 4.tgz

but I need to find latest file and attach to artifacts

```
success{

        archiveArtifacts '/home/user/images/current/latest_build_*.tgz',onlyIfSuccessful: true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your last stage for instance, you could fill a variable with the output of a shell command that gets you the last file by alphabetical order

define a global variable

```
@Field def lastFile

pipeline {
  ...
```

get the last file in the current folder

```
lastFile = sh (
    script: 'ls -Ar | head -1',
    returnStdout: true
).trim()
```

use the variable

```
success {
    archiveArtifacts lastFile, onlyIfSuccessful: true
}
```